# Can i convert PDF to PDF/A-1A with out api in php..?

Tags: php

How to Convert PDF to PDF/A-1A with API, Because I want to make an offline software.

Comment: You should start by doing some proper research and make some attempts. Right now, this question is _way_ too broad and unclear.

Comment: I have not found any use of the full resource.

Comment: It's unclear if you're asking to do this _without_ an API (which it says in the title) or _with_ an API (which it says in the question). If it's without, then you will most likely still need some third party software to help you with it. It's not a simple conversion and any solution in PHP would be _way_ too broad for this format. If it 's with, then SO is the wrong place since asking for recommendations/suggestions about third party resources are off-topic.